# PostgreSQL - can't use args in functions

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to write a simple function in postgresql, which checks if my table exists, and if it is, then clear its all rows. In postgresql docs I saw that I can refer to my arguments by $ plus number of arg, but it gives me an error during function create.

here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_if_exists(table_name text) RETURNS void
AS $$
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM $1)
THEN 
delete from $1;
END IF;
RETURN;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[image]

Comment: You can't use a parameter as a table name. You need to use dynamic SQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 1):

Variables in functions are not simply interpolated into the string, they are passed as parameters to a prepared query. As such, you can't use them directly in parts of the query that would change the plan, such as table and column names.

In order to do that, you need to instead use *dynamic SQL*, that is, build a string programmatically, and execute that. See [Executing Dynamic SQL in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

You should always be very careful when creating dynamic SQL, as it is easy to accidentally create security problems. At the very minimum, you should use the correct escaping mechanism, but you probably also want to whitelist or pattern match which table names the function is expecting.

An example of correct quoting using [the `format()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)'s `%I` placeholder:

```
EXECUTE format('delete from %I;', $1);
```

Note that you can also use the variable's name, rather than a positional identifier, which is much easier to read in longer functions:

```
EXECUTE format('delete from %I;', table_name);
```

I won't attempt to adapt your complete example, because I presume it's an over-simplified example anyway, since it doesn't actually make sense as written.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass identifiers (table names, column names) into a function you need to [execute the query dynamically](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Furthermore, instead of `DELETE FROM` without a filter you should use `TRUNCATE` as this is faster and it cleans up your hard disc (on the down side, changes can not be undone).

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete_if_exists(table_name text) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Just try to TRUNCATE
    EXECUTE format('TRUNCATE %I', table_name);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;  -- If the table does not exist, an error is thrown, just ignore it
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```